# docker-py: how can I check if the build was successful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to build myself a neat pipeline in Python 3. My problem, everything seems to be working nice, Jenkins always gives me a green bubble, but sometimes docker build fails to executed.

So `client.build` doesn't raise an error if the build breaks for some reason:

```
try:
    self.client.build(path=self.arguments.projectPath, pull=True, rm=False, tag=self.arguments.dockerImageTag)
except:
     print("Error: Docker did not build)
     raise
```

does not raise an error if the build failed.

Can someone please help me finding the right method, how I can be sure my build was done, and if not getting a valid message? I am totally lost.

Best regards
Mirco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.build` returns the messages outputted by `docker` when issuing the `docker build` command. Your initial mistake is in not capturing the response:

```
response = cl.build(fileobj=f, rm = True, tag='myv/v')
```

and if successful the contents look as they do if executed through the command line:

```
list(response)
b'{"stream":" ---\\u003e bb44cb7f2d89\\n"}\r\n',
# snipped for brevity
b'{"stream":"Successfully built 6bc18019ddb6\\n"}\r\n']
```

On error cases, for example, using a silly dockerfile:

```
# a dockerfile with a type in 'MAINTAINER'
f = BytesIO('''
# Shared Volume
FROM busybox:buildroot-2014.02
MAINTAIER first last, first.last@yourdomain.com
VOLUME /data
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
'''.encode('utf-8'))
```

The output contained in `response` looks like:

```
[b'{"stream":"Step 1 : FROM busybox:buildroot-2014.02\\n"}\r\n',
 b'{"stream":" ---\\u003e 9875fb006e07\\n"}\r\n',
 b'{"stream":"Step 2 : MAINTAIER \\n"}\r\n',
 b'{"errorDetail":{"message":"Unknown instruction: MAINTAIER"},"error":"Unknown instruction: MAINTAIER"}\r\n']
```

As you see, a `key` of `errorDetail` is contained containing the error message.

So, you can check for that, either with byte string search:

```
class DockerBuildException(BaseException): pass 


try:
    responce = self.client.build(path=self.arguments.projectPath, pull=True, rm=False, tag=self.arguments.dockerImageTag)
    for i in respone:
        if b'errorDetail' in i:
             raise DockerBuildException("Build Failed")
except DockerBuildException as e:
     print("Error: " + e.args[0])
     raise
```

Or, even better, by transforming each entry to a `dict` with `ast.literal_eval` and also using the message supplied to inform the user:

```
from ast import literal_eval

try:
    responce = self.client.build(path=self.arguments.projectPath, pull=True, rm=False, tag=self.arguments.dockerImageTag)
    for i in respone:
        if b'errorDetail' in i:
            d = literal_eval(i.decode('ascii')
            raise DockerBuildException(d['errorDetail']['message'])
except DockerBuildException as e:
     print("Error: " + e.args[0])
     raise
```

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but so far thank you very much for explaining so well.